# Why the php output can not insert into Vue data array

Tags: php, vue.js

I am learning basic Vue.js, when I fetch data using PHP, why it can not put into the Vue object data array

```
    data: {
        message: "vue?",
        homeView: true,
        brandView: false,
        flipF: true,
        flipB: false,
        prices:[
             {coffee1:15},{coffee1:12},
            <?php 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "{coffee1:".$row['price']."},";
                }
            ?>
        ]
    },
```

{{ item.coffee1}}

The php part could output {coffee1:20},{coffee1:18},  but they can not be shown on webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should fetch from an API which will serve JSON, but for sake of answering you should instead build your array, and then use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
<?php
$prices = [
 ['coffee1' => 15],
 ['coffee1' => 12]
];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  $prices[] = ['coffee1' => $row['price']];

?>
```

Now in your vue:

```
data() {
   return {
       message: "vue?",
       homeView: true,
       brandView: false,
       flipF: true,
       flipB: false,
       prices: <?= json_encode($prices) ?>
   }
},
```